# Ubertheme Magento 2.1.2 Migration Tool - iframe loading issues / 403 in the admin area

Tags: magento2

I've contacted the support staff from uberthemes, but they've been very little help & I'm seeing this issue all over the place with the latest iteration of their product.

I've got some logging running & I'm getting an error that is showing a problem with this section of code.

The error from the stack trace is "Uninitialized string offset: 0"

could someone point me in the right direction for troubleshooting this issue? I'm getting nowhere fast.

```
     * Sets the relative URL for the application entry script.
     * This setter is provided in case the entry script URL cannot be determined
     * on certain Web servers.
     * @param string $value the relative URL for the application entry script.
     */
    public function setScriptUrl($value)
    {
        $this->_scriptUrl='/'.trim($value,'/');
    }


     * Returns the path info of the currently requested URL.
     * This refers to the part that is after the entry script and before the question mark.
     * The starting and ending slashes are stripped off.
     * @return string part of the request URL that is after the entry script and before the question mark.
     * Note, the returned pathinfo is decoded starting from 1.1.4.
     * Prior to 1.1.4, whether it is decoded or not depends on the server configuration
     * (in most cases it is not decoded).
     * @throws CException if the request URI cannot be determined due to improper server configuration
     */
    public function getPathInfo()
    {
        if($this->_pathInfo===null)
        {
            $pathInfo=$this->getRequestUri();

            if(($pos=strpos($pathInfo,'?'))!==false)
               $pathInfo=substr($pathInfo,0,$pos);

            $pathInfo=$this->decodePathInfo($pathInfo);

            $scriptUrl=$this->getScriptUrl();
            $baseUrl=$this->getBaseUrl();
            if(strpos($pathInfo,$scriptUrl)===0)
                $pathInfo=substr($pathInfo,strlen($scriptUrl));
            elseif($baseUrl==='' || strpos($pathInfo,$baseUrl)===0)
                $pathInfo=substr($pathInfo,strlen($baseUrl));
            elseif(strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],$scriptUrl)===0)
                $pathInfo=substr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],strlen($scriptUrl));
            else
                throw new CException(Yii::t('yii','CHttpRequest is unable to determine the path info of the request.'));

            if($pathInfo==='/')
                $pathInfo='';
            elseif($pathInfo[0]==='/')
                $pathInfo=substr($pathInfo,1);
            if(($posEnd=strlen($pathInfo)-1)>0 && $pathInfo[$posEnd]==='/')
                $pathInfo=substr($pathInfo,0,$posEnd);

            $this->_pathInfo=$pathInfo;
        }
        return $this->_pathInfo;

    }
```

Comment: Which extension version you used to migration of data?

Comment: 3.0.2 - it's the newest version from ubertheme

Answer (score 1):

Our team has resolved [a similar case](https://www.ubertheme.com/question/404s-with-m2-1-2-ub-3-0-1/) that was caused by wrong files/folder permission.

Beside the file/foder permission, if you use Nginx server, the issue might associate with the additional configuration for Nginx (required for our migration tool to work properly) as well.

If the case above does not refer to your ticket on Ubertheme, please submit a new ticket or let us know your old ticket url here, so that we can check and help you out.

Regards,
Ubertheme team

Comment: https://www.ubertheme.com/question/404s-with-m2-1-2-ub-3-0-1/ it gives 404 Not Found

Comment: The ticket you mentioned was resolved today, yet the ticket's owner marked the ticket as private though. As indicated in our reply above, the folder permission might be one of the reason for either 404 or 403 issues.